# Open a file in flex 3

Tags: apache-flex, file

How can I create a .txt file using flex 3? And I want to write some datas in to this file...... Is it possible? Any one can help me?

Thanks in advance..
Nimmy

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
//set File object    
var file:File=File.documentsDirectory;

    file=file.resolve(“myFile.txt”);
//set Stream object
    var stream:FileStream=new FileStream();
//set FileMode
    stream.open(file, FileMode.READ);
    var data:String= stream.readUTFBytes(Stream.bytesAvailable);
//close file
    stream.close();
```

different **FILEMODE**:

> FileMode.APPEND: write only, append
>   new data to the bottom of the file;
>
> FileMode.READ: read only, file must exist;
>
> FileMode.UPDATE: both read / write the
>   data where positioned where you want;
>
> FileMode.WRITE: write only , if file
>   doesn't not exist, will be created
>   otherwise will be overwritten;

Comment: Note that the File object is only available if you're using AIR. If you're building a Flex RIA, the File object isn't available (for obvious security reasons). For more info: http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/langref/flash/filesystem/File.html